# cannot connect to the internet - stretch

Tags: dhcp

I am trying to get my pi 3B+ (stretch) back online but it does not work anymore. it was working until last week. plugging a windows PC on the same ethernet plug and using the same settings works. I cannot use dynamic IPs. the ethernet cable works, is not defective. /etc/network/interfaces was left unchanged,  as often suggested while configuring a pi with stretch on a static IP configuration

here is my /etc/dchpcd.conf

```
profile static_eth0
static ip_address = 141.20.67.77/23
static routers=141.20.66.1
static domain_name_servers=141.20.1.3/31

fallback to static profile on eth0
interface wlan0
inform 141.20.67.77
static routers=141.20.66.1

interface eth0
fallback static_eth0
inform 141.20.67.77
static routers=141.20.66.1
```

Comment: "I cannot use dynamic IPs" - why not? What are you doing that prevents you from using them? Are you sure the router isn't trying to assign that IP to another device? Is it possible for you to set up the static IP in the router config rather than on the Pi?

Comment: So, you're saying you are assigned 512 public IPv4 addresses?

Comment: If that is actually the contents of your `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` I am amazed it ever worked.  What does `ip a` and `ip r` show?

Comment: @Nathaniel: becuase that is how the network is managed at my workplace. Jaromanda: I do not understand what you mean sorry :). Milliways: could you explain why it should not work and what would be the proper configuration? Thanks all

Comment: @user879506 That's fair enough. It may be worth mentioning this in the initial question as it greatly limits the solutions people can provide. Most large networks do not allow devices to be assigned static IP addresses, so it has probably assigned that address to another device.

Comment: @user879506 Would it be possible to set up a RealVNC account as a test? This is free (for personal use) and if you actually create an account and add the Pi to your team, connecting to it will find the IP address automatically (if you enable cloud connection). This would require commenting out anything to do with the static IP, and just put auto eth0 for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your file, as described below:

```
nodhcp

interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.222/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1

interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.0.222/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1

interface wlan1
static ip_address=192.168.0.2224/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

Where

- 192.168.0.222 - it's static IP-address.
- 192.168.0.1 - IP-address of your router.

**You should update this data related to your case!**

if you have any questions, you can read full description [here](https://github.com/romankh3/raspberrypi-home-ecosystem/blob/master/BASE_CONFIGURATION.md#turn-on-raspberry-and-set-wi-fi-connection).

Comment: you're assuming the OP doesn't have a block of 512 public IP's that are part of a block of 65536 public IP's assigned to Humboldt University of Berlin (141.20.0.0 - 141.20.255.255) at his disposal

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying here :)

Comment: @user879506, add at the end of the file `/etc/dchpcd.conf` changes, which I've written and update them related to your static IP and IP of the router.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that you can't connect to the network, then reinstall raspberry OS into your SD card again and make two files,

One named **'ssh'** with *no extensions*

and the other named **'wpa_supplicants'** and type the below in the file

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
ssid="WIFI_SSID"
scan_ssid=1
psk="WIFI_PASSWORD"
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```